# Failed to read matching artifact container catalog resource

Tags: ibm-jazz, oslc

I am trying to integrate custom OSLC adaptor of third party tools with RQM. I am able to add it as a friend and seeing it in Friends section of RQM.

As a next step when I try to retrieve the resource it is failing - Failed to read matching artifact container catalog resource.

Failed to read matching artifact container catalog resource:

```
Unable to load URL: /qm/proxy?uri=http:/xyz.com:8080/appName/services/catalog/singleton, Status: 400
```

Any help to resolve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  I might suggest you read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a better idea on how to ask a good question.  You have good detail - but I'm not sure the community has enough info to help you diagnose/solve your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some background on what's going on which might help you diagnose your problem. These are assuming that you are writing a "provider" (server) for which RQM is the "consumer" (client).

1. I presume you have a "[Root Services document](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/RootServicesSpec#Root_Services_Documents)", whose URI you entered into RQM to to create the "Friend" relationship.
2. The URI that RQM is picking up and trying to request is the URI for the Service Provider Catalog from that Root Services document.

   - Try requesting the Root Services document yourself in your browser, copying the Service Provider Catalog URI it contains and loading that in the browser. If it does not work, then your app is reporting an incorrect URI, and you will need to fix that.
   - (The error message you included in the question starts "http:/" not "http://" - make sure that's not a typo in your Root Services document).
3. You can see that the request that RQM is making is going through "/qm/proxy". Any requests from RQM to your app go through a proxy in RQM, which checks the request URI against a whitelist of trusted servers.

   - Make sure that the host name in your Service Provider Catalog (the one in the error message, which should be the same as the one in your Root Services document) is the same as the host name displayed in the "friends" list in RQM.

---

*Disclaimer: My postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent the positions, strategies or opinions of my employer, IBM.*